# Why does the template literal type extend Record<string,any>?

Tags: typescript

Why does test1 return 1

```
type test1 = `${number}px` extends Record<string, any> ? 1 : 0; // test1 ==> 1
type test2 = `${number}px` extends object ? 1 : 0;              // test2 ==> 0
type test3 = `100px` extends Record<string, any> ? 1 : 0;       // test3 ==> 0
type test4 = `100px` extends object ? 1 : 0;                    // test4 ==> 0
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBMEM7AIxQLxQAYBIDeA7ArgLYBGEATgL5gAe6UE1suAJnFAEoQDGA9mcwB4EZAJa4A5gBooAQ1wgAfFAD8UZAC4oABgDcUAFAB6Q1FMA9ZftCQY8YACZUGHARLkqteowgs2PYgBW3MAqalCaukYm5pbW0LAIAMxO6IhaWjR0DEysHNx8gsJiUrLySqoa2jpRplAWVuDxdgAsKWkZntk+uf5BXCEV4VU1MUA)

Comment: `any` in `Record<string, any>` has got something to do here. It starts returning 0 as soon as we change from `any` to any other type. Interesting!!!

Comment: Not that surprised about `test1`, as `\`${number}px\`` extends `Record<keyof string, string[keyof string]>`, and therefore logically also `Record<keyof string, any>` and  supertype `Record<string, any>`. That begs the question why `test3` is `0`,even though `\`100px\`` extends `Record<keyof string, any>`.. Subtyping (assignability) is probably just a bit quirky on primitive types. https://tsplay.dev/NdjByW

Comment: @Oblosys Ask another question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71543570/why-do-interfaces-and-aliases-of-the-same-shape-have-different-results)