# Why do interfaces and aliases of the same shape have different results？

Tags: typescript

Has been using 'Equals' to do equality checks

```
type Equals<A1, A2> = (<A>() => A extends A2 ? 1 : 0) extends (<A>() => A extends A1 ? 1 : 0) ? 1 : 0;
```

but there's a problem

```
interface User {
    id: string;
    name?: string;
}
type test0 = Equals<User, { id: string; name?: string }>;
// test0  => 1   expect ok

type test1 = { id: string; name?: string } extends Record<string, unknown> ? 1 : 0;
// test1  => 1   expect ok

type test2 = User extends Record<string, any> ? 1 : 0;
// test2  => 1   expect ok 

type test3 = User extends object ? 1 : 0;
// test3  => 1   expect ok

type test4 = User extends Record<string, unknown> ? 1 : 0;
// test4  => 0    I can't understand  why?
```

if 'User' is an alias

```
type User1 = {
    id: string;
    name?: string;
};

type test5 = User1 extends Record<string, unknown> ? 1 : 0;
// test1  => 1   Unbelievable  why？
```

Why do 'test4' and 'test5' behave like this?
What did I get wrong?
What rules lead to this?
Is the 'Equals' type incorrect?

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwCMUC8UAGASA3gOwFcBbAIwgCcBfMADwyghuAjwBN4oAlCAYwHtyrADyJyASzwBzADRQAhnhAA+KAH4oKAFxQADAG4oAKAD0xqOYB6qw6EiwEwAExpMuQqQrU6DJi3ZQ+EgArXmA1DShtfRMzS2tbaDhEAGYXDCQdHVp6RmY2Dm5+QRFgcSlZBWVwrV09GPMoKxtwRIcAFjSMrO9cvw5AkJ4w9Rro0wam5rsAaQgQAHkAMxcAazm+Zex8YjIqbPq4wynWxABWNLcdz2yfPP9CgWE1kA2oUQkZN9KPgG1n1-eUgAuioRpFakZxodjvZEAA2FwAclEiNufS4vEeQn+y0Bnzxf3WuO+wNBESiBgOjWsMKSwAA7EiUWj8hiik8iV8yp9KmTRpSodSjglYcAABxM0qo3qsh7FPEVRR88H6KDjADqfAIABtWD5IEMIgALCgQAB0VMmMIAyiTJAAFch8MAANTk2oIECEMBU6B+MCBLP8PzlwgkiwoUFmIFk4cjbo9ECUgfUP2jsgTnsD2jwEAAbhRhS1RQBOFy27mO52Zr1bdy7LwYFTjAASRCIFTAYDk5BYwG1ICgAHdoKw+HhEWEZXrQ-JFsxyPJtdqLYLJiK6Rly3aq673Z6hMipUpLdYgA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because interfaces can be merged, so their properties are inferred

See here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42825, which describes exactly the same issue as you are describing here.

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42825#issuecomment-789242594
is the pertinent explanation

> > Why is IFoo not assignable to `Record<PropertyKey, unknown>` then? What
> > am I missing?
>
> This is exactly the train of thought that lead to anything being
> assignable to `Record<string, any>`, but there was concern from users at
> the time that then there was no way to indicate that they only wanted
> to accept things with a declared index signature. This makes a lot of
> sense if you intend to write to the received object, since if you
> alias an `IFoo` by a `Record<string, unknown>` then you can trivially
> corrupt it through e.g. `myAlias["type"] = 0`